# v-on:change event is not fired when javascript is used to increase value is Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building a retirement income calculator for work and started using Vue for the first time to integrate two-way data binding. I have developed most of the functionality of the calculator, however I am having some trouble implementing a couple business rules into the calculator due to unfamiliarity with Vue. The code I have completed can be viewed at https://jsfiddle.net/9f542pqs/. Here are the business rules that I need to apply:

- A user can select their current age as a range from 35-70.
- The minimum "contribute until" age that can be selected is 65.
- The maximum "contribute until" age that can be selected in 85.
- A user can contribute anywhere from  a minimum of 15 years  to a maximum of 30 years.
- Considering the above rules, when the user selects their current age as anywhere from 35-51, the minimum age that can be selected for the "contribute until" age is 65, and the button to decrease this age should be disabled.
- When the difference between the age a user has selected to contribute until and the age they have selected as their current age is 15 years, the button to decrease the "contribute until" age should be disabled.
- The same applies to when the difference between the ages is 30 years, then the button to increase the "contribute until" age should be disabled.
- When a button is to be disabled, the disabled attribute, along with a class of 'disabled' are to be applied.

I have tried to attach a `v-on:change` listener to the input used to store the "contribute until" age and then do a check of the business rules to set booleans that control the disabled state of the increase/decrease buttons, but the event never fires for me. How can I implement such functionality to disable the increase/decrease buttons when the value of the "contribute until" age is updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `change` event is only going to fire when the input's value is directly edited. It will not fire when it is changed by your dropdown or +/- buttons.

The good news is, you don't really want a `change` event from the DOM. You've bound the value to a variable, and what you want to notice is when that variable's value changes. That's what [watch](http://vuejs.org/api/#watch) is for. You'll do something like:

```
...(in your Vue spec)...
watch: {
  age: function (newValue, oldValue) {
    validate(newValue);
  }
},
...
```

(Also note: since you're using `v-model="age"`, you don't need `value="{{age}}"`)

I notice that you're applying Vue separately to various DOM elements. You're likely going to want those various items to be aware of each other. You probably ought to be making one call to Vue for the whole application, and possibly having each of those sub-units be represented by a component.

Think of Vue not as a way of adding two-way binding, but as a way of segregating the DOM from your programming. You deal with application state purely as data, and Vue makes sure the DOM reflects that state.

Comment: Thanks Roy. I will try out what you've suggested and see how it works out for me. Might you have any suggested resources for learning Vue? I'll continue to go through their documentation and guides, but is there anything else you'd suggest?

Comment: @Rick I learned Knockout first. I don't know whether it's the best way to get into Vue, but has a great tutorial at http://learn.knockoutjs.com/ and it's actually a bit simpler. The main thing is to get into the practice, every time you want to touch the DOM, of thinking what you need to do in your viewmodel.